# How to retrieve the salesmans that has sold an item to every client (another column)

Tags: mysql, sql

first time here. I'm a beginner
IM USING MYSQL.

I'm having trouble to get the ONLY SALESMAN who have SOLD a product to every CLIENT on the list
Compare the SALESMAN column with the CLIENT_KEY and return the value.
Could be only one salesman or two, I don't know.

This is a long list +8K transactions.

Below is a picture of the database

[image: 1]

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried.  That is worth putting in the question as well.

Comment: also "every CLIENT on the list " means you have a table for clients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you only have one table and all clients means all distinct client keys from your table.

```
SELECT SALESMAN
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY SALESMAN
HAVING count(DISTINCT CLIENT_KEY)=(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CLIENT_KEY) FROM YourTable)
```

The query sums all clients for each salesman, and checks if that number is equal to the sum of all distinct clients in the table.

Answer (score 0):

if client list is a table then :

```
select salesman 
from salesManTable s
group by salesman
having count(distinct clientid) = (select count(*) from clienttable)
```